# find is not considering the variable

Tags: linux, shell

I am running the command below I set the value already to `$DATE` variable, but the below command is showing nothing, find will not consider the variables or anything wrong with my syntax.

```
find . -name '*.log.$DATE-0000'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not `find`'s fault. It's a shell problem: Variables are expanded in double quotes, not in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it was not expanding in your command so you need to use double-quotes as follows,

```
find . -name "*.log.$DATE-0000"
```

Comment: Still won't work, the variable is still enclosed by single quotes which prevent variable expansion. Replace the single quotes with double quotes in the question.